# Kohana orm inheritance

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I want to auto creating parent record on creating children.

Example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `front_end_users` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `addr1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `addr2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_userid` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `logins` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `reset_token` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_failed_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `failed_login_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `promouter` (
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `balance` float NOT NULL,
  `commision` float NOT NULL,
  `mountly_fee` float NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `promouter_ibfk_1` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `front_end_users`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `front_end_users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `promouter`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `promouter_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `front_end_users` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

users->front_end_users->promouter
```

I want if I create `promouter` with login, password and address than automatically inserts appropriate fields in users `(login, password)`, front_end_users `(addr1, addr2, userid)` and promouter `(userid)`.

And I have several roles. So I can not add have_one to user model. But I added have_one to front_end_users and promouter models.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger parent creation on child creation then I think you should use trigger(s) on database level.

EDIT:

Create a table with the following scheme:

```
Rules(ID, TableName, ColumnName, Event, Action, Parameters)
```

You will have a set of Rules then and you will be able to make a general implementation for this. In your business layer you will call your rule parser (which also has to be implemented by you) and this way you can make any logical triggers in your business layer. I hope this helps.

Comment: means storing a class that kept the field related to other tables. And not just a blank table for a trigger.